Weird Discover update caused boot confusion
I am using Kubuntu 22.04.5 with 5.15 Linux kernel. Discover app said it has some system updates. I checked and it was a couple of python things and one thing that had lib in it. I do not know how to check the most recently updated settings (packages???). I also updated snapd with apt before this.
It said I needed to restart the system so I did. The boot menu where the Kubuntu logo is shown had a percentage bar for some reason. Then it asked me where to boot into, Ubuntu (Kubuntu???) was one of the options and it booted correctly, but it usually boots automatically into Ubuntu (Kubuntu???). I noticed nothing else wrong, but I want to diagnose exactly what happened in order to avoid future headaches.
Can you please tell me why this happened or how to figure out what happened myself?

The percentage bar you saw during the boot process is usually related to the initramfs update. You can check which packages were recently updated with grep " upgrade " /var/log/dpkg.log Please read the three words marked by ??? in your question and edit your question to update them to the correct choice of the two alternatives or else comment and tell me which words to choose.
